# Removing Photorec recovered files

Tags: testdisk

I have number of folders (over 60 folders) located in my file system folder and two folders with lock symbol on folder icon `recup_dir.1`, `recup_dir.2` and `photorec.ses`. I have removed testdisk using Synaptic Package Manager. But these folders are still there. Any help?

Comment: What is the content of these directories? Did you sucessfully retrieve your files?

Answer (score 2):

When you run photorec / testdisk, you need root access to use them. Because of this, you end up with the folders that are created in a Read only state. You don't have permission to write or delete them.

What I normally do is one of the following actions:

- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type: `gksu nautilus`

  [image]

  Then navigate to where your folders are and **DELETE** the folders.
- In the terminal go to where the folders are and do the following:

  `chmod 777 FOLDER/ -R`

  assuming FOLDER is the main recovery folder and inside of it are all the recovery folders. You can change the `777` value to a `700` if you do not feel safer from others looking on the computer ^^.

If the folders are not inside a custom (Eg: home/recoveryfolder/recup_dir.X....) then you must apply the `chmod` to each folder seperately or do something like this in home:

`chmod 777 recup_dir* -R`

This should bring back the access permission to all recup_dir folder for you.

Comment: ok now i have used the first step and removed the files in the file system folder but i couldn't access the folders in my home(recup_dir.1, recup_dir.2 and photorec.ses)

Comment: @user151010 try the new method.

Answer (score 1):

force remove the folders as root.

```
sudo rm -rf recup*
```

this will remove all directories starts with 'recup'.